# jquery scroll with in three column fiddle link

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have three column. I want to scroll all three column  in  opposite direction at the same  time.

I follow fiddle link. this work for two column I want to make same functionality for three column

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QDUyR/1/)

```js
// Add event listener for scrolling
$("#left").on("scroll", function() {
  var scrolledleft = parseInt($("#left").scrollTop()) * -1;
  console.log(scrolledleft + scrolledright)
  $("#right").scrollTop(scrolledleft + scrolledright)
})

//Move right column to bottom initially
$("#right").scrollTop($("#right").height())
  //Get actual distance scrolled
var scrolledright = parseInt($("#right").scrollTop())
```

```css
#left {
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
}
#right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
    dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
    dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
    occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
    nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui
    officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
    ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
  <div id="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
    dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
    dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
    occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
    nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui
    officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
    ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I means http://jsfiddle.net/QDUyR/1/ like in this link two column scroll .I want same funcitonality in three column

Comment: Apply the same strategy for the "two column" scroll to a third column. Where specifically are you getting stuck?

Comment: I m stuck with performance concern of scrolling.Its moving too slow in case of three column

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use percentages since the blocks won't be the same size (usually)

how about this, does it help ? [(JsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/QDUyR/41/)

```
// Add event listener for scrolling odds
$(".scrollSide:odd").on("scroll", function () {
    var trueDivHeight = $(this)[0].scrollHeight;
    var divHeight = $(this).height();
    var scrollHeight = trueDivHeight - divHeight;
    //console.log($(".scrollSide:odd"));
    var scrolledleft = 1+(parseInt($(this).scrollTop())/scrollHeight)*-1;
    //console.log(scrolledleft);
    $(".scrollSide:even").scrollTop(function(){
        var trueDivHeight2 = $(this)[0].scrollHeight;
        var divHeight2 = $(this).height();
        var scrollHeight2 = trueDivHeight2 - divHeight2;
        console.log(scrolledleft*scrollHeight2);
        return scrolledleft*scrollHeight2;
    });
});

// Add event listener for scrolling evens
$(".scrollSide:even").on("scroll", function () {
    var trueDivHeight = $(this)[0].scrollHeight;
    var divHeight = $(this).height();
    var scrollHeight = trueDivHeight - divHeight;

    var scrolledleft = 1+(parseInt($(this).scrollTop())/scrollHeight) * -1;
    //console.log(scrolledleft);
    $(".scrollSide:odd").scrollTop(function(){
        var trueDivHeight2 = $(this)[0].scrollHeight;
        var divHeight2 = $(this).height();
        var scrollHeight2 = trueDivHeight2 - divHeight2;
        return scrolledleft*scrollHeight2;
    });
});

//init even scrolls at the bottom
$(".scrollSide:even").scrollTop(function(){
        var trueDivHeight2 = $(this)[0].scrollHeight;
        var divHeight2 = $(this).height();
        var scrollHeight2 = trueDivHeight2 - divHeight2;
        return scrollHeight2;
    });
```

I changed the part where you use IDs in order to use classes, and it is applied on odd and even selections ... you can have as many as you want with this code, just replace the odd and even selections with the classes you desire

[update]

it works but I think that there are performance concerns since each of them scrolls the other back on the chain events triggering (programmatically, it should go into an infinite loop but it doesn't!)

Comment: Is there any solution of performance concerns when scrolling?

Comment: @satyamCoder that was my expectation, although it is not shown in action. I need to investigate this further to confirm if there are performance issues. but you can use it so far as it doesn't seem to have problems,, it's just my assumption that I wanted to share.